# Open source lecture notes textbook in "introductory real analysis"

Tags: undergraduate-education, textbooks

So far I wasn't able to find one single open source set of lecture notes or textbook ***with $\LaTeX$ source code available*** on "introductory real analysis" that could suit my needs. It seems to me that you can find either sloppy calculus books or books whose very first chapter is on Banach Spaces. Could you point out something in the middle: that is, some open source lecture notes that cover the same material covered by Rudin and Ross and treat the subject with rigour?

Comment: I maintain a catalog of free/open-source books. Analysis books would be here: http://www.theassayer.org/cgi-bin/asbrowsesubject.cgi?class=Q#freeclassQAmg

Comment: @BenjaminDickman I don't really like that book (both formatting and content).

Comment: @BenjaminDickman Trench's book seems really good. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in [Zakon's Analysis I](http://www.trillia.com/zakon-analysisI.html) and [II](http://www.trillia.com/zakon-analysisII.html). It is free for personal use, it is rigorous, it covers the same content as Rudin and Ross. I haven't personally studied it, but it looks good.

Comment: It really looks very good. Thank you. But cannot find the source code even though I see that it is released under creative commons license.

Comment: @Dal Not sure you'll be able to find that. Why do you want to edit them?

Comment: The main aim of the question is to find *editable* lecture notes so that one can take his own notes more easily.

Answer (score 1):

(Migrated from the comments.)

Below are two different textbooks that may fit the bill.

First, note that the OP has previously asked a more general question about textbooks **[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1027936)** on MSE. That earlier question included an answer with the Intro to Real Analysis book **[here](http://www.jirka.org/ra/)**, which has the LaTeX on the same page: scroll down to Source. The textbook is available as a free **[pdf](http://www.jirka.org/ra/realanal.pdf)**, too.

The text has been used at a bunch of quality institutions, from UW-Madison to UC-Berkeley, and it has a favorable **[MAA review](http://www.maa.org/publications/maa-reviews/basic-analysis-introduction-to-real-analysis)** from 2013 (of the December 2012 version of the text). Although it has been updated as recently as December 2014, the citation on google scholar is given as:

> Lebl, J. (2011). Basic analysis-introduction to real analysis. *AMC, 10*, 12.

For another free text (with available TeX) see **[here](http://digitalcommons.trinity.edu/mono/7/)** for Trench's (December 2013) work.

The recommended citation there is given as:

> Trench, William F., "Introduction to Real Analysis" (2013). *Books and Monographs*. Book 7.

Its description:

> Using a clear and informal approach, this book introduces readers to a rigorous understanding of mathematical analysis and presents challenging math concepts as clearly as possible. This book is intended for those who want to gain an understanding of mathematical analysis and challenging mathematical concepts.

Moreover, the page notes that:

> This book was previously published by Pearson Education. This free edition is made available in the hope that it will be useful as a textbook or reference.

A citation for the earlier version is:

> Trench, W. F. (2003). *Introduction to real analysis*. Upper Saddle River, NJ: Prentice Hall/Pearson Education.